# Program still able to open root only files after setuid and setgid

Tags: c, linux, permissions, setuid

I'm writing a program which will operate as different users based on authentication. The program is setuid root and uses PAM authentication before dropping privileges.

I'm using `setuid()` and `setgid()` to drop privileges after authentication.  But apparently this isn't enough as after calling these my program still seems to have access to `open()` root only files.

Any suggestions?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Code to drop Priv
int u = 1000, g = 1000;

printf("Starting User %d Group %d\n", (int) getuid(), (int) getgid());
printf("Setting User %d Group %d\n", u, g);
if (setgid(g) || setuid(u)) {
    printf("Could not set uid or gid %d", errno);
    return 0;
}
printf("Have set User %d Group %d\n", (int) getuid(), (int) getgid());
```

The output of from this is:

```
Starting User 0 Group 0
Setting User 1000 Group 1000
Have set User 1000 Group 1000
```

And yet after calling this code my program can still open a file which is root only permissions:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root   root    505 May  5  2015 rootFile
```

The code to open is simple enough:

```
// Later
int fd = open("rootFile", O_RDONLY);
if (fd == -1) {
    // Never happens
} else {
    // Happens
}
```

Comment: What is `pritnf`? Any other copy errors?

Comment: No. it was just I'm using a modified `printf` function and had to replace those function calls to make it make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this article: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/POS36-C.+Observe+correct+revocation+order+while+relinquishing+privileges

Looks like you may have "problem" with suplementary groups. Before setting gid and uid do

```
setgroups(0, NULL);
```

and your code should work.

Comment: Thanks that pointed me in the right direction. I'm going to use `initgroups()` for this purpose.